# JavaScript not working with Form Submit button

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this on my PHP page:

```
<script>
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('test_form').submit();
}, 5000);
</script>
```

And it's working fine.

But when I'm placing this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</input>
```

the JavaScript timer is not working. When I remove this, JavaScript works all fine. What's the problem and how it will be resolved?

Comment: Give the element a different `name` (and maybe `id` as well).

Comment: Also, [learn how to **debug** JavaScript code](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: `</input>`? Since when `input` has closing tag?

Answer (score 1):

try changing name of your submit button like,

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn">Submit</input>
```

Because when you name your button **`submit`**, you override the **`submit()`** function on the form.

Comment: `type="submit_btn"` should still be `type="submit"` though ;)

Comment: I believe it's ID attribute, not name, that overrides form properties

Comment: I changed ID and name and it worked. Thanks a lot!!!